# Deleting a self intersecting face by its number

Tags: export, meshlab, finite-element-analysis, face, self-intersection

I have a mesh that I import to the Meshlab and simplify, clean, and reconstruct the mesh. I export the final mesh from meshlab and import into finite element software (COMSOL). While importing, I received the error message of "Self intersecting face,   Face:19303".

Meshlab cannot find any self-intersecting face. How can I select the face 19303 and modify/delete it to fix the error?

thanks,
Hamed

Comment: Hi, Hamed. Did the answer of Dominic solve your problem? If so, can you validate the answer?

Answer (score 2):

In my version of Meshlab (v1.3.2_64bit on Lubuntu), the recipe for selecting the face seems to be the following:

1. Click "Filters > Selection > Conditional Face Selection"
2. Write `(fi == 19303)` to "boolean function".
3. Click "Apply".

Once the face is marked, Meshlab lets you remove it.

I suppose that `fi` stands for "face index" (it would be great if someone could confirm/correct this). And beware that Meshlab numbers the faces starting from zero; if COMSOL numbers them from one, you might be off-by-one.

Another posibility would be exporting the mesh in a format in which each triangle has its own line ([off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OFF_(file_format)) for instance) and counting the lines in your editor. But this would be tedious and error-prone.